# Infinite loop with a singleton - does this type of issue have a name?

Tags: design, object-oriented, singleton, errors

I ran into an unusual error while working on my project. To better learn from and remember it, I'd like to know if this type of error has a name or some definition. (The error itself `OutOfMemoryError` isn't unusual, I'm talking about what lead to this error).

My (simplified) situation was this:

I had a class `Singleton`:

```
class Singleton extends ClassA{
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton(){ // implicitly calls super() }

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if (instance==null) instance = new Singleton();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And it's superclass `ClassA`:

```
abstract class ClassA{
    public ClassA(){
        ClassB objectB = new ClassB();
        // .. some logic ..
    }
}
```

And a class `ClassB` that uses `Singleton` in it's constructor:

```
class ClassB{
    public ClassB(){
        Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
        // .. some logic ..
    }
}
```

What happens is the following:

1- `ClassB` is instantiated somewhere. It's constructor is invoked and calls `Singleton.getInstance()`.

2- `Singleton.getInstance()` sees that `instance == null` and executes `instance = new Singleton()`.

3- The constructor of `Singleton` is run. It's empty, but it implicitly calls the superclass' (`ClassA`) constructor.

4- The superclass of `Singleton` instantiates a `ClassB` object `new ClassB()`.

5- `ClassB`'s constructor is invoked and calls `Singleton.getInstance()`...

Since the instantiation of `instance` in `Singleton` never reached it's finish, `instance == null` still returns `true`, and the cycle never ends.

Resulting in an infinite loop, that finally resulted in an `OutOfMemoryError`.

So my question is: **is this kind of infinite-loop-with-singletons error a common issue?** **Any ideas how I can avoid it in the future?**

Comment: Best way to avoid it: Don't use singletons.

Comment: Like whatsisname mentions, it's best not to use a singleton; they're essentially a global variable. Additionally, ask yourself if you really need to use inheritance; favor composition.

Comment: @Doval This probably belongs in a different question, but I think the main problem with global state is that it's hard to know what changes the state so it's hard to rely on it. But I only use singletons for *immutable* state. It's simply a pool of constant data objects can use. For example the app I'm working on generates music. The singleton is used to store all the notes and chords so objects can access them without instantiating them all the time. What's the problem with this?

Comment: @Prog If you're accessing an immutable value, that's fine, although I question the need for lazy initialization. I guess the bigger question is, why do you have a cyclic dependency and do you really need to use inheritance?

Comment: @Prog why not just pass your configuration object (here your singleton) into `classB`s constructor when creating a new instance of `classB`? Or, if it changes, pass it into the method needed, or update it with a setter.

Comment: I think the better question is why the Singleton inherits from `classA`.

Comment: Cyclic dependency?

Comment: Is this a theoretical experiment? If not, what do `classA` and `classB` represent in a real project? The cycle can be broken with a better design by knowing what `classA` and `classB` represent.

Comment: @RSahu The Singleton is a class called MusicalResources. It contains Notes, Chords and Scales that can be accessed by any object in the system that wants to. ClassA is the abstract Scale class, superclass of all scales. ClassB is CMajor class, a subclass of Scale. Actually now the cyclic dependency is quite obvious: MusicalResources instantiates a CMajor object because it needs to contain all the Scales, and CMajor invokes `MusicalResources.getInstance()` because it needs access to the Notes that compose it. Thing is, I'm not sure how to break this cyclic dependency.

Comment: I think the common name for this problem is, "YOU'RE USING A SINGLETON" ;)

Comment: @RobY I see no problem with using a singleton that holds only immutable state (which is what I'm doing). If there is a problem with it, please explain it.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with a singleton. You would have the same problem even if Singleton was not a singleton. Creating a new S causes A's constructor to be called which causes B's constructor to be called which causes a new S to be created which causes A's constructor to be called which causes B's constructor to be called which causes a new S to be created which causes A's constructor......

Comment: You avoid this problem by drawing a class diagram and being aware of dependencies. Cyclic dependencies should be eliminated. In your case, A knows about B. B knows about S which implicitly means it knows about A. That's a problem. There is seldom a need for 2-way dependencies. A class shouldn't know who contains it.

Comment: @Prog I'm not too versed in music theory but it seems to me you could construct all the notes first, then collect those into scales, then collect all of that into MusicalResources. But if there's a finite set of notes and scales, then you likely want to be using enums. Enums *can* contain members (instance variables and methods).

Answer (score 7):

It is a simple [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) during initialization, independent of the Singleton. There are three classes that instantiate each other in a cycle: A instantiates B, which instantiates C, which in turn instantiates A again, and you have an endless instantiation cycle.

Another thing that needs to be evaluated is why do the objects have a circular dependency on each other regardless of instantiation. That is, even if somehow they were all instantiated, they should not still have a circular dependency since that is often indicative of high [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) and possibly other design issues.

Having said that, it seems that the Singleton is not yet completely implemented, because it does not guarantee singleton across multiple threads. When the locking necessary for a singleton implementation is coded, it will very quickly run into a deadlock.

Usually, these types of errors are found:

- At design time by looking at class interactions,
- At implementation time by working through the code in the head,
- At compile time as some compilers might detect and issue warnings/errors,
- At runtime, by getting the kind of exception this code raised.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways to break the cycle.

1. Don't instantiate a `CMajor` when instantiating `MusicalResources`. Let a higher level function construct the necessary `Scale`s. Any time a `Scale` is constructed, add a reference to `MusicalResources`.
2. Don't query `MusicalResources` for the `Notes` when constructing an instance of `CMajor`. Query them on an as needed basis.

Answer (score 0):

One of the downsides of Singletons is how they interact with super and sub classes. Another downside of Singletons is nesting them -- that gets messy fast. No offense, but I find it a little funny when you say, "I don't see the problem..." when in fact you are seeing a problem that blows up your runtime engine ;)

Aside from that, your model is all kitty-wampus. Again, no offense, but...! I think, for example, you're making an equivalence between a Scale and a Note that messes up the hierarchy. I'd take out the Singleton code first, and then step back and make a diagram of the is-a and has-a relationships (for example, it might be cleaner if Scale "has a" Note instead of "is a" Note)

It might be good to diagram it out, with the classes, subclasses, and instances laid out with arrows between them.

If you're dishing out immutable reference objects, bundling them up as public static final members of some container class is a lot cleaner and less nastiness-prone than Singleton. Also, I'm not sure where, but I think that enums are going to be your friends here too.

(Enums are kind of the Java-approved version of immutable Singleton, again without the nastiness.)